# SQL - Alias in CASE statements

Tags: sql-server

I have this piece of code (please look below). I keep getting error: "Invalid column name 'SuppFinish2'

```
SELECT

CASE
    WHEN [RegFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [RegFinish]
END AS [RegFinish],

CASE
    WHEN [SuppFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [SuppFinish]
END AS [SuppFinish2],

CASE
    WHEN [RegFinish]<[SuppFinish2] THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS [TEST]

FROM TABLE
```

Is it because of [SuppFinish2] being an alias? Thanks!

Comment: Consider ISNULL() rather than CASE

Comment: You can't reference other fields selected in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Comparing `RegFinish <  ''` is probably not what you want, describe the logic for that condition when `SuppFinish` is `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use those aliases in the same level as you created them, becuase they are not existing yet.. wrap your query with another select like this:

```
SELECT * ,
       CASE
            WHEN [RegFinish]<[SuppFinish2] THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
       END AS [TEST]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [ID],
        CASE
            WHEN [RegFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
            ELSE [RegFinish]
        END AS [RegFinish],
        CASE
            WHEN [SuppFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
            ELSE [SuppFinish]
        END AS [SuppFinish2],
    FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I add another column into this query? For example I want to add [ID] from same Table.

Comment: @atomoutside updated , just need to place in in the inner query

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As you said its due to alias and aliased columns can be referenced only on order by to logical query flow order

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN [RegFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [RegFinish]
END AS [RegFinish],

CASE
    WHEN [SuppFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [SuppFinish]
END AS [SuppFinish2]
FROM TABLE
)
select 
CASE
    WHEN [RegFinish]<[SuppFinish2] THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS [TEST]
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to reference aliased columns, you can use a derived table (or CTE, but that is not shown here)

```
Select *, CASE
WHEN [RegFinish]<[SuppFinish2] THEN '1'
ELSE '0'
END AS [TEST] From
(
SELECT

CASE
    WHEN [RegFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [RegFinish]
END AS [RegFinish],

CASE
    WHEN [SuppFinish] IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE [SuppFinish]
END AS [SuppFinish2]
) T1
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, at the same time, set and access an alias in the `SELECT` clause. I would suggest rewriting your query using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.[RegFinish],
       t2.[SuppFinish],
       CASE
          WHEN t1.[RegFinish] < t2.[SuppFinish] THEN '1'
          ELSE '0'
       END AS [TEST]
FROM TABLE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE([RegFinish], '') AS [RegFinish]) AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE([SuppFinish], '') AS [SuppFinish]) AS t2
```

Comment: Honest question: how is cross apply better than using a CTE or derived table?

Comment: @Jeremy It's just syntactic sugar in this case I guess. To my taste it looks more compact and clean this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL([RegFinish],'') as  [RegFinish]
     , ISNULL([SuppFinish],'') as [SuppFinish2], CASE 
WHEN  
  ISNULL([RegFinish],'') < ISNULL([SuppFinish],'') THEN 1
                                                   ELSE 0 
END  AS [TEST]
FROM TABLE
```

Why not use ISNULL instead of CASE? The problem with your query is that [SuppFinish2] is an alias not an column and can only be used in `ORDER BY` clause